# Reduce duplication in postgres plpgsql function with CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, common-table-expression

In a SQL function I can return a boolean if I do

```
with myquery as (delete from mytable where id = 'value1' returning 1)
select exists (select * from another_function('value2') where (select count(*) from myquery) > 0);
```

But in a plpgsql function it doesn't work and gives error `query has no destination for result data`.

In this function I want to execute `another_function` if any rows were actually deleted from `mytable`. The problem is I'm repeating the entire `select exists` part, because I'm using that in multiple functions.

Is it possible to move more of that logic into `another_function`? So that I can do something like this?

```
with myquery as (delete from mytable where id = 'value1' returning 1)
select * from another_function('value2', myquery)
```

How can I pass the CTE into a function so I don't need to repeat the `select exists` and `where (select count(*) from myquery) > 0)` every time I want to call `another_function`?

Comment: I"m just baffled.  `another_function` in one case takes one argument and in another two, where the second argument is . . . .what?  A CTE?  A tuple?  I think you should ask a new question with more specifics about what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect an auxiliary function to take an argument, such as the `id` being returned from the `delete`.  It would then look like:

```
with d as (
      delete from mytable
      where id = 'value1'
      returning id
     )
select another_function('value2', d.id)
from d;
```

This operates one value at a time, but that is typically what one would want.  If you wanted all ids passed in at once, you could use an array:

```
with d as (
      delete from mytable
      where id = 'value1'
      returning id
     )
select another_function('value2', array_agg(d.id))
from d;
```

Comment: Thanks and do you know how I can get the first query in my question to not throw `query has no destination for result data` error when it's defined as `returns boolean`? It works when using sql function but not plpgsql.

Comment: @user779159 . . . If this is inside a function, you need to store the value somewhere.

Comment: Regarding the `query has no destination for result data` error, if it was a regular sql function with `returns boolean` my first query would work. 

But if I change it to a plpgsql function then I get the error. Normally I can return a boolean from a plpgsql function by doing something like `return (select exists(.......))`. Why isn't that possible here?

If I wrap the whole `with` in a `return` I get `WITH clause containing a data-modifying statement must be at the top level`.